# SharePoint 2016 modal popup undefined error

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, modal-dialog, sp.ui.modaldialog.showmodaldialog

Platform: SharePoint 2016

I am trying to use SharePoint's pop-up modal in SharePoint 2016 but it worked once and after a few minutes it stopped. I get the following error
**'OpenPopUpPageWithTitle' is undefined**

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', myPopUp());
});


function myPopUp() {
    var lsDate = localStorage.getItem("lastConnected");
    var tDate = new Date().toDateString().substring(4);
    if ((lsDate == null || lsDate == undefined) || (lsDate != tDate)) {
        showPopup();
        localStorage.setItem("lastConnected", tDate);
    }
}

function showPopup() {
    var url = "/SiteAssets/popup/my-Popup.html";
    var width = 680;
    var height = 470;
    OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(url, function(){return}, width, height, "Attention");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After googling, this worked for me

````
    $(document).ready(function() {  
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', showModalPopUp);  
    });  

    function showModalPopUp() {  
        //Set options for Modal PopUp  
        var options = {  
            url: '/sites/HOL/Pages/Custom-Publishing-Page.aspx?IsDlg=1', //Set the url of the page  
            title: 'SharePoint Modal Pop Up', //Set the title for the pop up  
            allowMaximize: false,  
            showClose: true,  
            width: 600,  
            height: 400  
        };  
        //Invoke the modal dialog by passing in the options array variable  
        SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);  
        return false;  
    }  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the code below to achieve it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(myPopUp,'sp.ui.dialog.js');
function myPopUp() {
    var lsDate = localStorage.getItem("lastConnected");
    var tDate = new Date().toDateString().substring(4);
    if ((lsDate == null || lsDate == undefined) || (lsDate != tDate)) {
        showPopup();
        localStorage.setItem("lastConnected", tDate);
    }
}
function showPopup() {
    var url = "/SiteAssets/popup/my-Popup.html";
    var width = 680;
    var height = 470;
    OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(url, function(){return}, width, height, "Attention");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @LZ_MSFT, I get the following error when I try the above code:  ```'ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded' is undefined```